# Creating 'custom' tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I’ve hit sort of a roadblock in a current project I’m working on, I don’t have a lot of web developers in my office and as a matter in fact the only other web dev just went on vacation. Anyway I was wondering if anyone could help me with structuring two of my postgres tables.

The user needs to be able to create custom data tables, one for each specific program (a parent record). The form I’ve setup for these tables allows you to add or remove inputs based on how many fields you need and then specify the name, data_type, etc.

My initial idea was to create a new table in the dB each time a user created one of these custom tables. The other web dev, who has created something similar, said it would be better to create a fields table that stores each custom field information and then have a data table that stores every cell of data tying to a field id.

I understand having the fields table so that I can retrieve just the field information and build my front-end tables and edit forms dynamically, but I’m a little confused on how to get the data into the table. I’m used to having an array of objects and each object relating to an entire row. But with this method it’s storing each cell of data instead of row of data and I don’t know the best way to select and organize it on the backend.

Data for these tables are going to be imported in from CSV files formatted to the custom table structure, below is the current structure I have for my two tables. I got a suggestion on reddit to use JSON to store each rows data, but I'm wondering how I'll be able to do sorting and filtering with this data. My current table structure is listed below, and this is before I got the suggestion to use the json data. I'm guessing if I went that route I would remove the fieldId column and instead use it for 
the JSON key name, and store that fields data with it.

**fields**
id -- name -- program_id -- type -- required -- position -- createdAt -- updatedAt

**data**
id -- fieldId -- data -- createdAt -- updatedAt

So I guess my question is does this sound like the right way to structure these tables for my needs and if so can I still perform sorting and filtering on it?

Comment: Are there many different fields? How much do they differ from program to program? Is the set of fields per program constant? How many different programs are there?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the program fields are consistent, programs is parent table where records can be added, edited or deleted but the fields are consistent. When you view a specific program there is a production table and a claims table, they are both custom tables where the user defines the fields prior to uploading data.

Comment: Then why not use a single table?

Comment: Postgres has alternatives such as JSON that might also be feasible.  However, if the other dev has a recommended approach, the two of you should figure out together what is best.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the productionData table doesn't have consistent fields. I am using a single table for programs but in each program there are two custom tables that the user needs to create the fields for. Thus why I have a fields table tying to program id, and the data tying to fieldId.